# Create simple gui for changing json variables

Tags: json, qt, user-interface

i have no real programming experience and while i hope you can help me with very simple tutorials / solutions i am also willing to learn something.

I want to create a gui that helps the user change settings of an JSON file (in this case) without the need to edit it directly. In detail it should do:

- edit predefined variables
- show, add, remove lines at parts of the file and edit their variables
- simple user input (little text / numbers) / choose from a dropdown
- if possible little questionmark-icon for each variable that will show explanations as a hover box
- save changes + start an exe

would be great if there already is a editable script/solution with this features
i also found that Qt Designer is recommend very often - do you know tutorials can help me with the things i want to do?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a [QJsonModel](https://github.com/dridk/QJsonmodel) for Qt5 with a little example how to use it. Through this model, a part of the problem has already been solved.

For adding and delete items I suggest you familiarize yourself in [Qt Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). Here is a [Model/View Tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html).

For saving you should look at [QJsonDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html) Class.

To start an application [QProcess::start()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) and/or [QDesktopServices::openUrl()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) are your friends.

Good luck

Comment: It seems to be very complicated and time exhausting to me. I guess luck is what i need ^^^ thank you!